# Populate Bootstrap dropdownlist dynamically

Tags: c#, javascript, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown">
Year <span class="caret"></span>
</button>

<ul id='demolist' class="dropdown-menu" runat="server" role="menu">

</ul>
</div>
```

Hi All, 
I am trying to populate the li items in a bootstrap dropdwnlist via code-behind. PFB the .cs code which is placed in page load.

```
        HtmlGenericControl li;

        for (int x = 3; x <= 10; x++)
        {
            li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            li.Attributes.Add("class", ".dropdown p");
            li.InnerText = "Item " + x;
            li.Disabled = false;
            demolist.Controls.Add(li);
        }
```

PFB the js code which displays the selected value upon click.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

    $(".dropdown-menu li ").click(function(){

    $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
    $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());

    });

      });
    </script>
```

Now, when i click on the dropdown it displays the list items,but there are 2 problems

1. When the mouse cursor is hovered over it 
   display a 'I' cursor (the one that appears when you are editing a doc or something) instead of finger pointer cursor(like how it displays for an asp:dropdown).
2. After clicking the list item the text of the dropdown do change, but the 'down arrow' disappears.

Could anyone please help me out on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the text of the button with jQuery .text(), you're overwriting the span class="caret" too.

Perhaps add another span into your button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="year">Year</span> <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Then target that with your JS:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li").click(function(){

    var li = $(this),
        btn = $('.btn:first-child'); // Maybe need a better selector?

    btn.find('span.year').text(li.text());
    btn.val(li.text());

});
```

Also the cursor won't be a pointer as you're hovering over an li, not an a etc. But you could tweak your CSS to chose the cursor style:

```
.dropdown-menu li {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```